# jQuery's stop() seems to be blocking animations that haven't been queued yet

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

How does jQuery's `stop()` actually work?

If you look [here (http://jsfiddle.net/hWTT6/)](http://jsfiddle.net/hWTT6/), when you hover over the main blue box it should fade to red, and when you hover off it should fade back. The problem is it will completely fade to red (and then back to blue) even if the mouse has hovered off before the first fade was complete. The problem can more clearly be seen with the slide effect. Hover over the slide "button" and the main box will slide to blue, hover off, it will slide back. But try hovering on and off and on and off, before the first animation has completed. You'll see that all four animations are carried out. I included both examples here to show it is not just a problem with one effect or something.

I thought this would be easily fixed by adding a `stop` before the animations, as shown commented out in the code. But, if I do this the current animation will stop and the following one will never start. Almost as though `stop` is blocking an animation that is occurring *after* the call to `stop`.

What am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: I always thought `stop()` kills the queue.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing that `.stop()` accepts two arguments. Both boolean, indicating:

```
- clearQueue (first)
- jumpToEnd (second)
```

So by calling `$('#foo').stop( true, true ).doSomeOtherStuff()` you should get your desired goal.

Reference: [`.stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: Yep, that bit me the first time I used it too. Seems the normative use case for `stop()` should actually be the behavior `stop(true, true)` rather than the its default behavior, but I didn't write the library ;).

Comment: Thanks, I was aware that it took the two bools but had misunderstood how they work. This gets me much closer to the desired result but really I don't want to `jumpToEnd` of the first animation, I want it to stop where it is and then continue the next animation from there. I tried `(true,false)` but this still prevents the second animation from running. Perhaps this can't be achieved with `stop` alone.

Comment: @tjm: As I said in my answer, if you do not want to complete the animation, you need to get the state back to a workable condition at some point, and specify the target of the animation in a non-toggle way.  See my update.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the CSS is getting messed up by stopping at arbitrary points.

The `fadeIn()`, `fadeOut()`, `slideUp()` and `slideDown()` move from the current state to a new one and then revert to that - not to the original CSS.

You need to fix the CSS back in to a usable state to continue with after the .stop(), or more clearly specify the animation targets.

As the others have said, you can get the CSS to the correct position, by ensuring that when you stop the animation, it jumps to the end of it, rather than leaving everything in an arbitrary state.

**UPDATE:**

Take a look at the code in this update of your demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/hWTT6/5/

It might not be exactly how you want it to perform, but the trick, if you do not want the animation to run its course, is to get the animation back in to a state that it can continue from in the way in which you desire.

```
$(function() {
    $('#fade')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $('#fg_fade').stop().animate({ 'opacity': 0 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#fg_fade').css('height', '100%');
        });
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $('#fg_fade').stop().animate({ 'opacity': 1, 'height': '100%' }, 'slow');
    });

    $('#slide_fire')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $('#fg_fade').stop().animate({ 'height': 0 }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#fg_fade').css('opacity', 1);
        });
    })  
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $('#fg_fade').stop().animate({ 'height': '100%' }, 'slow', function() {
            $('#fg_fade').css('opacity', 1);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Orbling. That solves it and explains nicely how the built-in animations relate (or not) to the original css. If I'd worded the question slightly differently you'd definitely be getting "the tick", but since I focused on `stop` I'm not sure what to do. I'll have a think and come back to it. But thankyou, that's very helpful.

Comment: @tjm: Aye, I see the issue - addressing the underlying problem is not necessarily the same as answering what you have asked. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could set the stop() options to (true, true) so that you cancel all events in cue and jump to the end of the previous animation. look at the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/hWTT6/4/

Answer (score 1):

The stop method can be called in the following difference ways:

```
.stop(true); 
//Same as:
.stop(true, false); //Empty the animation queue only


//Or
.stop(true,true); // Empties the animation queue AND jumps to the end


//Default
.stop()

//Same as

.stop(false,false);
```

There may be a better way using .animate instead: [Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/bp4uK/1/)

```
$(function() {
    $('#fade')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $('#fg_fade').stop().css('height', '10em').animate({'opacity' : '0'}, 'slow');
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $('#fg_fade').stop().css('height', '10em').animate({'opacity' : '1'}, 'slow');
    });  


    $('#slide_fire')
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $('#fg_fade').stop().css('opacity', '1').animate({'height' : '0'}, 'slow');    
    })  
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $('#fg_fade').stop().css('opacity', '1').animate({'height' : '10em'}, 'slow');
    });

});
```

This way the animation stops when you want it to and still runs the next animation.

The problem with doing `.stop` then `slideUp/slideDown` or `fadeIn/fadeOut` is that the animation can end prematurely and keep an incorrect height/opacity.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is caused by the way `fadeIn`, `fadeOut` etc. work.  You may expect them to fade between 0 and 1.  However, in reality they fade between 0 and whatever the "baseline" opacity is.  You can see this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hWTT6/7/

You'll notice I set the initial opacity to `.5`.  Now when I call `fadeIn` it does not fade all the way in to `1` it fades to my baseline of `.5`.  Your problem occurs when you stop the animation prematurely, the "baseline" becomes whatever the opacity is at the time it is stopped.  Now when you call `fadeIn` on `mouseleave` it tries to fade to this new baseline and finds it is already there.  You can see this illustrated by going here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hWTT6/8/  (original, but with `.stop`)

If you place your mouse over `slide` and then remove it half-way through the animation, it will stop in the middle.  Now place your mouse back over `slide` and wait for the animation to complete.  If you now remove your mouse, you will see that it slides back down to the place where the first animation was stopped.  That is because this is the new "baseline".

The way that you would solve this is actually to replace `fadeIn`, `fadeOut`, etc. with a more explicit animation.  For instance, use `fadeTo` to tell it to fade between `0` and `1`:

http://jsfiddle.net/hWTT6/6/

Notice that since I am telling it to fade to `0` or `1` everything works.  A similar thing could be done to replace `slideUp` and `slideDown` using `animate`.