# jquery eventually stops working

Tags: jquery

I am making a dropdown menu with the following script, the dropdown effect works the first few mouse hovers but then stops working, any ideas? thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

    $("ul.topnav li").hover(function() { 
        $(this).children().fadeIn(800); 
    },
    function() { 
        $(this).find("ul.subnav").stop().fadeOut(800);
    }) 

});
```

Comment: here is a link to the problem page: http://joepolitic.com/flogicmockorig.html

Comment: the "problem" page seems to be working now, can you post what you did to fix it?

Comment: I used .fadeTo as described below by kingjiv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is interrupting `fadeIn` or `fadeOut` prematurely.  When you do this, the item gets a new "baseline" opacity.  `fadeIn` does not fade to an opacity of `1`, it fades to the baseline (for example, if your element has an opacity of .8 originally, and you hide it, `fadeIn` will fade to .8 not 1).

To fix this issue, use `fadeTo` with an opacity of 1 instead of `fadeIn`.

EDIT:  Found one of my previous answers with a more thorough explanation with fiddles to illustrate the idea.   [jQuery's stop() seems to be blocking animations that haven't been queued yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6549802/jquerys-stop-seems-to-be-blocking-animations-that-havent-been-queued-yet/6550229#6550229)

Comment: oh thanks this sounds like the problem, I noticed it was getting progressively more opaque, how do I set the opacity though, I don't see it http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: Ok I used .fadeTo as per your fix in your previous post works like a dream thx a million

Answer (score -1):

I think the selecor is wrong. If you are fading in children of ul.topnav li then I guess you wanted to fadeOut the same child.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){  

      $("ul.topnav > li").hover(function() { 
            $(this).children().fadeIn(800); 
      },
       function() { 
        $(this).children().stop().fadeOut(800);
      }) 

});
```

Comment: i did that originally, but if I do that, the whole topnav li item fades out and totally disappears after the first mouseout

Comment: still the same problem both the original topnav list item and the subnav disappear completely